# How to write execution result of script to a file?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sqlplus

I have a script a2create . I must save execution result file. Instruction say remember to put sql plus command set echo on in the front of your file. I tried this

```
@a2create set echo on
```

or

```
set echo on @a2create
```

or

```
@a2create set echo on a2.lst
```

but did not work.
I want to write the result to a file which is a2.lst. Appreciate if anyone can help.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following,

```
define spool_file = 'a2.lst'
SET ECHO OFF
SET NEWPAGE 0
SET SPACE 0
SET PAGESIZE 0
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET HEADING OFF
spool a2.lst;
@a2create
spool off;
```